# How can I make to extract the words from my sentence an from the dependency graph in the next order:current_Word,governor,dependent and relation type

Tags: java, xml, stanford-nlp

I have this sentence:

> She will celebrate Easter
>
> And I have this dependency graph:

```
  <dependencies style="typed">
      <dep type="nsubj">
        <governor idx="3">celebrate</governor>
        <dependent idx="1">She</dependent>
      </dep>
      <dep type="aux">
        <governor idx="3">celebrate</governor>
        <dependent idx="2">will</dependent>
      </dep>
      <dep type="dobj">
        <governor idx="3">celebrate</governor>`enter code here`
        <dependent idx="4">Easter</dependent>
      </dep>
      <dep type="punct">
        <governor idx="3">celebrate</governor>
        <dependent idx="5">.</dependent>
      </dep>
    </dependencies>
```

How can I extract the words to make the next result:
 result= current_word+governor+dependent+relation_type

governor means "who depends on me" and dependent means :who is my governor.

I have the following code:

```
public static String depRel(String graph) throws SAXException, IOException,
        ParserConfigurationException {
    String xml_String;
    String[] split_Sentence = graph.split("\\s+");
    xml_String = Features.dependency_Graph(graph);
    String result = "";
    String dependent = "";
    String governor = "";
    String type = "";


    Document document = convertStringToDocument(xmlString);
    document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    Element root = document.getDocumentElement();
    NodeList nList = document.getElementsByTagName("dependencies");
    for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
        Node node = nList.item(temp);
        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Element eElement1 = (Element) node;

        }
        NodeList nodesDocPart = node.getChildNodes();
        for (int temp2 = 0; temp2 < nodesDocPart.getLength(); temp2++) {

            Node n = nodesDocPart.item(temp2);

            if (n.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element el1 = (Element) n;
                type = el1.getAttribute("type");
            }

            // /////////////////////////////////////////////////sentence/////////////////////////////////////////////
            NodeList nodesSentencePart = n.getChildNodes();
            for (int temp3 = 0; temp3 < nodesSentencePart.getLength(); temp3++) {
                Node sentence = nodesSentencePart.item(temp3);
                if (sentence.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                    Element eElement4 = (Element) sentence;
                    if (eElement4.getTagName().equals("governor")) {
                        governor = eElement4.getTextContent();
                        result = governor + 
                                + dependent + ":" + type;

                    } else if (eElement4.getTagName().equals("dependent")) {
                        dependent = eElement4.getTextContent();
                        result = dependent  + governor
                                + ":" + type;

                    }

                }
                for (int i = 0; i < splitSentence.length; i++) {
                    if (split_Sentence[i].equals(dependent)) {

                        result = split_Sentence[i] + governor + dependent
                                + type;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Rez=> " + result);
            }

        }

    }

    return result;

}
```

And this is the method that make a graph on a sentence:

```
I want for every word the next output:
result=current_Word+governor+dependent+relation_type.
```

Method dependency_Graph make a dependency graph for a given sentence.
    The output appears for many times and the words does not appear.I have tried to retain the initial sentence in a variable  but it does not worked.
    I don't know how can I return the result for every word in the sentence just once as a String because I will reuse it in another method.
    I don't know how can I make if I have more dependencies for a word because I must retain just three.
    I must save the results in a Comma Separated Values  file to process it after that in a machine learning  tool .Any idea how can I obtain this result with the code that I have?Thank you in advance!